# how to get a sharepoint item using powershell?

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

I wanna check sharepoint title first and see if the lib doesn't have that related file.

all I know first using a spweb, than do what? how to get the value of that colum?

Comment: possible duplicate of [use powershell to access sharepoint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107818/use-powershell-to-access-sharepoint)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Search Sharepoint for a file check this Link out:
http://www.thorntontechnical.com/tech/sharepoint/quick-tip-sharepoint-powershell-get-items-in-a-list-based-on-custom-columns-and-other-hints

To Check out use following Code:

```
$Site = Get-SPWeb $siteurl
$Site.GetFile($myFile).CheckOut()
```